# Sorting ArrayList<Object[]> by objects inside (String, Date, etc.) in reverse order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Assume that there is an `ArrayList<Object[]>` containing various objects inside:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Object[]{"cat", (long)1422355945});
list.add(new Object[]{"dog", (long)1422355970});
list.add(new Object[]{"rat", (long)1422355900});
```

How can we sort this list effectively by first `Object` (which is `String`) in reverse order? And to do the same by second `Object` (which is `long`)?

Comment: By writing an appropriate comparator.

Comment: Yes, I expected this answer. Could we share real examples here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a Comparator, similar to the example below:

```
    List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Object[] { "cat", (long) 1422355945 });
    list.add(new Object[] { "dog", (long) 1422355970 });
    list.add(new Object[] { "rat", (long) 1422355900 });

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object[] o1, Object[] o2) {
            int cmp1 = ((String) o1[0]).compareTo((String) o2[0]);
            if (cmp1 == 0) {
                return Long.compare((Long) o1[1], (Long) o2[1]);
            }
            return cmp1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: How can we do that in reverse order (just by one column)?

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis For that column, compare o2 with o1, instead of o1 with o2.